# How can I solve TensorBoard 404 error?

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, tensorboard

I try to use TensorBoard, I just use tf.summary.histogram() for each conv layer, logits, and loss function.

when I write the `tensorboard --logdir = 'TB_dir' --port=6006` command to see the visualization, it does not represent the histogram information also it gives me this::

> WARNING:tensorflow:path ../external/data/plugin/text/runs not found, sending 404
>   WARNING:tensorflow:path ../external/data/plugin/text/runs not found, sending 404
>   WARNING:tensorflow:path ../external/data/plugin/text/runs not found, sending 404
>   WARNING:tensorflow:path ../external/data/plugin/text/runs not found, sending 404

I tried to use `sudo pip3 install tensorflow-tensorboard` command, but this does not solve the problem.

***I use Tensorflow version 1.1.0, Ubuntu 17.04, and python3.5***

in my code in training step I used:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
 summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(TensorBoard_dir, g)
```

after I used all histogram summary function I used:

```
   merged_summaries = tf.summary.merge_all()
```

and the last thing after **tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession**() I write ::

```
  while not sess.should_stop():
    _, summary = sess.run([train_op, merged_summaries])
    summary_writer.add_summary(summary,10)
```

I do not know if I miss any thing for using TensorBoard in the code??

Comment: I think it is --logdir,  have you tried this

Comment: oh sorry My write is wrong in the question. yes, I use --logdir  not logdir

Comment: I will edit it in the question thanks for observation

Answer (score 1):

I was hosting tensorboard on a remote machine and forwarding it to my local computer manually and having a similar error.

I hosted the tensorboard at 6006 but instead of forwarding it to 6006, I forwarded it to 6007 and the problem got solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try either reinstalling TensorFlow 1.1, or upgrading to TensorFlow 1.3. The tensorflow-tensorboard pip currently only works for TensorFlow 1.3.